# How to count constraints in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

I am interested in where to look to find techniques to approach the following problem:

Let $M$ be a smooth projective manifold, and let $S \subset M$ be some submanifold.

Consider on $M$ a complete linear system of divisors $|D|$ whose generic elements do not contain $S$. In this context, there is a natural constraint problem: What is the dimension of the subspace $|D|_{\supset S}$ of elements of $|D|$ that do contain $S$?

In particular, I am interested in the case where the submanifold $S$ is a curve, so that $D$ and $S$ generically intersect in a number of points.

*Edit: For special arrangements, the number of resulting constraints may be fewer, and very difficult to determine in general. However I am only interested in the generic, expected result.*

As a simple example, take $M=\mathbb{P}^3$, $S$ to be an intersection of two linear polynomials, and $|D|$ to be the linear system of quadratic polynomials. In this simple case, one can use something like the theory of resultants to show that $\mathrm{dim}|D|=10$ and $\mathrm{dim}|D|_{\supset S}=7$.

In more complicated situations I think that one needs, and that there should exist, a more general framework.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem in general that we still cannot answer even for curves in $\mathbb P^2$. The *expected* behavior in the plane is known as the Harbourne-Hirschowitz conjecture.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks a lot for your helpful comment. It seems I must be phrasing my question far too generally. Would it help to specify that the field is $\mathbb{C}$? Or that the curve is connected and irreducible? In this case, the problem is I think very easy on $\mathbb{P}^2$, or on $\mathbb{P}^n$ more generally.

Comment: No, none of these assumption help. We really do not know if a general set of points in $\mathbb P^2$ imposes independent conditions on polynomials.

Comment: @TabesBridges The connectedness assumption would in that case imply a single point, and so an easy problem. I might expect this assumption to also simplify the higher-dimensional situation. More generally, while special arrangements of the curve(s) may indeed lead to fewer imposed constraints, I would be very interested in a reference dealing with the generic case.